# Expo React Native app crashes on production logging NSInvalidArgumentException: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282292620)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I'm using React Native with expo, I have been stuck on this for quite some time. This occurs in production environment on iOS devices when starting the app. I tried running npx expo start --no-dev --minify and this is what logs after the app crashes -> (NSInvalidArgumentException: -[EXReactAppExceptionHandler handleSoftJSExceptionWithMessage:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282292620)

I need help!

The app runs as usual in development mode except when I publish the app.
I tried running the app in dev mode, the above error logs in console.

Comment: If it works in dev, but not prod, then I would first look at the code signing. Start simple. Is your Apple Store account current with no errors noted on their dashboard? Can you install the production app on a local device? Answer those questions first. It may solve the issue.

Comment: @MikeS. After publishing the app using expo publish, when I try to start the app it crashes, as that happened I went back to starting the app with (npx expo start --no-dev --minify), it runs the app as in production and still, the app crashes (in iOS devices only). But when I run the app in development mode using (npx expo start) , the app doesn't crash

Comment: Launch the app through Xcode if you can. Since you're using expo, you may be using Windows. TBH, I don't use expo, so I won't be much help debugging ios apps with it. If you haven't already, I'd check the Discord Reactiflux server, the #help-react-native channel.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Currently having the same issue!

Comment: Turns out I was using a component that wasn't compatible - fortunately found a replacement easy enough!

Comment: I have been facing this issue and it's killing me since a week. How did you find out which component was not compatible?

Comment: Turns out, when opening the app on expo after expo publish, the app crashed on iOS devices (in the expo app). After sending the app for review to apple developer account, i tested the app on TestFlight, and the app doesn't crash. The app went to be accepted by apple and it works fine. It only crashes in the ios expo app when opening the published one via expo publish